# How to find the size of a variable without using sizeof

Tags: c, sizeof

Let us assume I have declared the variable 'i' of certain datatype (might be int, char, float or double) ...

**NOTE:** Simply consider that 'i' is declared and dont bother if it is an int or char or float or double datatype. Since I want a generic solution I am simply mentioning that variable 'i' can be of any one of the datatypes namely int, char, float or double.

Now can I find the size of the variable 'i' without sizeof operator?

Comment: why don't you want to use sizeof() ?

Comment: Found a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219199/size-of-a-datatype-without-using-sizeof

Comment: A similar question is here, by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219199/size-of-a-datatype-without-using-sizeof

Comment: @codingfreak: there is no variable of unknown datatype in C, as far as I know. Could you give an example of how you'd like to invoke the function/macro/... that you are looking for?

Comment: This sounds like an interview question.....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the following macro, taken from [here](http://www.geocities.com/vijoeyz/faq/c/sizeof_impl.html):

```
#define sizeof_var( var ) ((size_t)(&(var)+1)-(size_t)(&(var)))
```

The idea is to use pointer arithmetic (`(&(var)+1)`) to determine the offset of the variable, and then subtract the *original* address of the variable, yielding its size. For example, if you have an `int16_t i` variable located at `0x0002`, you would be subtracting `0x0002` from `0x0006`, thereby obtaining `0x4` or 4 bytes.

However, I don't really see a valid reason not to use `sizeof`, but I'm sure you must have one.

Comment: Darn ... trying it and getting the syntax right for my first C code in ages made me slow ;-)

Comment: I think this logic would be helpful to find the size of a datatype but how about a variable of unknown datatype

Comment: What do you mean by unknown, how would you declare it ? If you have a variable like, say, `int i`, `sizeof_var(i)` will give you its size.

Comment: Let us suppose you have simply forgot for what datatype you have declared the variable 'i'. What I mean to say is irrespective of the datatype to which it has been declared we should still be able to find the size of the variable 'i'

Comment: Responding to your edit, the macro works independently of the type of `var`. You can have either `char i` or `long i`, and `sizeof_var(i)` will return the correct result on both counts.

Comment: This fails at the end of the memory range.

Comment: @JoãoSilva 2 points : 1. The link in your answer preamble is broken 2. if i is of type int16_t (i.e. 2 bytes) the subtraction/macro evaluation should return 2 and not 4 isn't it ?

Comment: This may cause undefined behaviour if the address is not representible in `size_t`  (e.g. segmented architecture), and it's also not guaranteed to return the correct size

Comment: any specific reason behind `size_t`' use?

Answer (score 8):

It's been ages since I wrote any C code and I was never good at it, but this looks about right:

```
int i = 1;
size_t size = (char*)(&i+1)-(char*)(&i);
printf("%zi\n", size);
```

I'm sure someone can tell me plenty of reasons why this is wrong, but it prints a reasonable value for me.

Comment: Hey I mentioned it clearly that i can be of any datatype of the 4. In the above code you were simply using it as a int to say that the size of variable 'i' is 4 bytes

Comment: The only thing you need to fix is change `void *` to `char *` - you're not supposed to do pointer arithmetic with `void *`.

Comment: @caf: really? i remember listening that `void *` acts the same was as `char *` in pointer arithmetic and `gcc` didn't complain about that even with `-Wall`.

Comment: @codingfreak: So? Only the type of i needs to be changed to get a different result. The type of `size` should probably be `size_t` for correctness and clarity.

Comment: there is some issue with padding, the compiler can insert some free space between variables (well, it could even reorder them but I know of no compiler that do it).

Comment: @kriss: i know of padding, but I don't think it applies here, as I'm only referencing a single variable. Alignment might be another issue, which might falsify the result (or are alignment & padding considered equivalent in C? I'm not a C expert by far ;-))

Comment: I checked, it's OK with padding sizeof does the same and includes padding in the size of var. Hence it woks exactly the same.

Comment: Using (char*) instead of (void*) would avoid compiler warnings about void* arithmetic and does give the same result because a char has always size 1.

Comment: @drhirsch: I don't doubt that but I can't get gcc 4.3.3 to emit those warnings (even with "`-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`"). Which compiler (or which compiler switches) should I use to get those warnings?

Comment: Correction: actually "-pedantic" enables -Wpointer-arith which emits the warning about pointer arithmetic with `void *`.

Comment: This will work on processors that have byte addressable memory.

I am not sure whether this would work on the DSP56300 series processors where char and int are both stored in individual 24 bit wide memory locations.  The processor does not have byte addressing so the difference between the pointer values for successive chars or ints will both be 1.

Comment: @Ian: irrelevant. `sizeof` is defined in terms of `char` units, so the result will be correct. If your implementation uses 24 bit chars but artificially restricts them to 8-bit range, then it's not C. C mandates that `char` does not have padding bits.

Comment: @uɐɪ, on that machine, an `int` and a `char` are both one `char` worth of memory. Everything checks out. CRAYs had everything (!) 32 bits wide, for performance.

Comment: @JoachimSauer `gcc` does lots of funky stuff. Pointer arithmetic on `void *` makes no sense, but gcc accepts it as an extension.

Answer (score 2):

This works..

```
int main() {
    int a; //try changing this to char/double/float etc each time//
    char *p1, *p2;
    p1 = &a;
    p2 = (&a) + 1;
    printf("size of variable is:%d\n", p2 - p1);
}
```

Comment: `p2 - p1` should be `(int)(p2 - p1)` to match the format specifier `%d`

Comment: And you need casts for the pointer conversions: `p1 = (char *)&a;`

Answer (score 1):

```
int *a, *b,c,d;/* one must remove the declaration of c from here*/
int c=10;
a=&c;
b=a;
a++;
d=(int)a-(int)b;
printf("size is %d",d);
```

Comment: an accompanying explanation would be nice.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that below code would solve your problem in c++ without using sizeof() operator

for any variables like (int, char, float, double, char, short and many more...)

here I take integer,

```
int a;
```

then 
show it as byte addressable output,

```
cout<<(char *)(&a + 1) - (char *)(&a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#define xsizeof(x) (char *)(&x+1) - (char *)&x
```

Comment: Multiple problems: parenthesize the macro argument in the expansion and parenthesize the whole expression to avoid precedence issues: `#define xsizeof(x)   (size_t)((char *)(&(x)+1) - (char *)&(x))`

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work for every datatypes

#include<stdio.h>
struct abc
{
 int a;
 char b;
 int c;
};
void main()
{
 struct abc A;//FINDING THE SIZE FOR A STRUCTURE VARIABLE
 struct *ptr=&A;
 printf("SIZE:%ld\n",(void*)(ptr+1)-(void*)(ptr));

 int i=10;//FINDING THE SIZE FOR AN INT VARIABLE
 int *ptr1=&i;
 printf("SIZE:%ld\n",(void*)(ptr1+1)-(void*)(ptr1));
}
```

Comment: You have got the idea, but you should use `char *` instead of `void*` and the conversion specifier for `ptrdiff_t` is `%td`.  Note also that you do not need du define a pointer, you can use `&A` and `&i` directly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
#define sizeof_type( type )  ((size_t)((type*)1000 + 1 )-(size_t)((type*)1000))
```

For  the following user-defined datatype,

```
struct x
{
    char c;
    int i;
};

sizeof_type(x)          = 8
(size_t)((x*)1000 + 1 ) = 1008
(size_t)((x*)1000)      = 1000
```

Answer (score -1):

This should give you the size of your variable

```
#define mySizeof(type) ((uint)((type *)0+1))
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour (although so does the topvoted solution)

Answer (score -1):

Program to find Size of the variable without using `sizeof` operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
  {
  int *p,*q;
  int no;
  p=&no;
   printf("Address at p=%u\n",p);
  q=((&no)+1);
  printf("Address at q=%u\n",q);
  printf("Size of int 'no': %d Bytes\n",(int)q-(int)p);

  char *cp,*cq;
    char ch;
  cp=&ch;
  printf("\nAddress at cp=%u\n",cp);
  cq=cp+1;
  printf("Address at cq=%u\n",cq);
  printf("Size of Char=%u Byte\n",(int)cq-(int)cp);

  float *fp,*fq;
  float f;
  fp=&f;
 printf("\nAddress at fp=%u\n",fp);
  fq=fp+1;
  printf("Address at fq=%u\n",fq);
  printf("Size of Float=%u Bytes\n",(int)fq-(int)fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define GET_SIZE(myvar)   ((char)( ((char*)(&myvar+1) )- ((char*)&myvar) ))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Multiple problems: parenthesize the macro argument in the expansion and do not cast the result as `(char)`: `#define GET_SIZE(myvar)   (size_t)((char *)(&(myvar)+1) - (char *)&(myvar))`

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

struct size1


  {
int a;
char b;
float c;
};

void main()
{
struct size1 *sptr=0;  //declared one pointer to struct and initialise it to zero//
sptr++;                 
printf("size:%d\n",*sptr);
getch();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Below statement will give generic solution:

```
printf("%li\n", (void *)(&i + 1) - (void *)(&i));
```

`i` is a variable name, which can be any data type (char, short, int, float, double, struct).

Comment: C does not allow pointer arithmetic on `void *` pointers. This is (typically) a GNU C extension.

Comment: You have got the idea, but you should use `char *` instead of `void*` and the conversion specifier for `ptrdiff_t` is `%td`.