# how to find size of pointer without using sizeof in C

Tags: c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the size of a variable with out using sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393394/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-variable-with-out-using-sizeof)

using C, can we somehow find the size of a pointer without using sizeof operator ? though i found this question at lot of places while googling, but i couldn't find any answer. any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Do you mean the size of the pointer itself, or the size of the data type that it points to ?

Comment: I believe the pointer size is always constant - 4 bytes for 32-bit applications and 8 bytes for 64 bit.

Comment: Why do you need this?? Just curious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1393412/1086425

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Not neccesarily. In recent versions of 64 bit OS you can find support for binaries using a 64 bit execution model in a 32 bit address space. The main idea is to relieve cache pressure by cutting the size of pointers by one half.

Comment: @datenwolf: Yeah. And if you want it generalized to past that to other types like int or long, nothings constant there. Then there's the OS factor, architecture, and word length.

Comment: You could declare an array of pointers and take the difference between two adjacent elements, but it doesn't make sense to complicate things that much.

Comment: It is a shame to close this as a duplicate since the accepted and most popular answer at the “original” is not strictly conforming to C, but an answer here is. It would be better to reopen this and close the other as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a small but legal hack that you can use:

```
int *unused = NULL;
int **ptr = &unused;
printf("%tu\n", ((char*)(ptr+1))-(char*)ptr);
```

Here is how it works:

- Recall that adding `N` to a pointer adds `N` times the size of the type pointed to; hence `(ptr+1)` adds `sizeof(int*)` to the "raw" value of `ptr`
- `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so casting to `char*` lets you subtract "raw" values; the result is the `sizeof` added by the `(ptr+1)` operation.

Comment: How is that equal to `sizeof(int*)`?

Comment: @Linuxios I was missing an asterisk - added it now.

Comment: Now that's clever! +1. By the way, I like the power button Dr. Watson.

Comment: Haha, I kind of like it.

Comment: This is the mark of a C program. Hacks, and pointer manipulation that has to be explained to you.

Comment: @Linuxios That's what happens when one tries to avoid using facilities provided by the language :) It goes without saying that I would immediately dismiss anyone from the company for writing this type of code in place of a `sizeof`.

Comment: Almost legal. The code was printing a `ptrdiff_t` type with a specifier for `unsigned int`. I fixed it by inserting “t”, to make the specifier “%tu”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `ptrdiff_t` is a `signed` integer type, so I think the specifier should be `%td`, though it could be a problem only with a very large difference, and this is not the case...

Comment: @effeffe: sort of. `printf` is funny, it says that the arguments *must* have the correct type for the format code even though for varargs in general it's OK to read a small positive value as an unsigned type when it was passed as the corresponding signed type. Nobody seems to know why `printf` is more strict than varargs in general, but it means the code has UB. I'm pretty sure all known `printf` implementations use varargs normally, so there'd be no problem.

Comment: @SteveJessop that's true. However, I made a mistake in my previous comment, the problem of large numbers is in conversion from unsigned to signed, not the reverse. Too late to edit. Anyway, in the general case, the difference could be negative so it's not a good practice to print it like an unsigned value.

Comment: @effeffe: C 2011 7.21.6.1 7 says that **t** “Specifies that a following **d**, **i**, **o**, **u**, **x**, or **X** conversion specifier applies to a **ptrdiff_t** or the corresponding unsigned integer type argument…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, and you're providing a `ptrdiff_t`, not the corresponding `unsigned` type, right? I read it like _"%td is for ptrdiff_t, %tu is for an unsigned ptrdiff_t"_, since there's not a standard `unsigned` version of `ptrdiff_t`, but maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: You can't legally calculate `ptr+1` when `ptr` is a null pointer. It should point to an actual `int*` object.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think you're right - this is now fixed.

Comment: @effeffe: I read it as “**t** specifies that **u** applies to a ptrdiff_t or **t** specifies that **u** applies to the corresponding unsigned integer type argument”. In other words, `printf` is required to work if you pass a `ptrdiff_t` and use **t**. The wording is somewhat awkward, though. In general, how would you know what the corresponding unsigned integer type is? You could for a particular implementation, but generally not when writing for portability. But, yes, we could use “%td” and avoid the issue.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : thanks for the reply. i thought of one more possible way...to count the number of hex digits in any address (the value of a pointer variable), but the issue here is that leading zeroes in the address may not be present. please let me know if the problem can be worked  this way also. thanks

Comment: @user1182722 Textual representation of a pointer is fundamentally a wrong thing to explore because of some serious differences in representation among hardware platforms. For example, in the code compiled for the Harvard architecture (where pointers to code and pointers to data do not share the same address space) a pointer may add a whole extra byte, yet only one bit of it may be used. This solution, on the other hand, will work regardless of the underlying architecture.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define MY_SIZEOF_VAR(x) ((int)((char*)(&(x)+1)-(char*)&(x)))
#define MY_SIZEOF_TYPE(x) ((int)((char*)((x*)0+1)-(char*)0))
```

This is nowhere near as good as the real thing. You might prefer it to be an unsigned int, but you can't be too fussy!

Answer (score 1):

You can check what architecture you're on. If it's a 32bit architecture the pointer size is...32bit, or 4 bytes. 64bit arch has 64bit, 8b pointers.

Comment: Not completely necessarily. There are (technically) exotic architectures that have different pointer sizes. But much simpler than my solution. +1.

Comment: Not true on all architectures. Usually the bits refers to data bus word, not address bus word. @Linuxios not so exotic architectures,  Intel architecture did this. For example real mode has 1MiB address space, but only 16 bit bus wide.

Comment: Aha, didn't know what. But it should work on all common architectures(i386, x86, amd64 etc) right?

Comment: @dutt: x86, it should. amd64, probably. ARM, no idea. Same with other (somewhat) common architectures like PPC or others.

Comment: @Linuxios Ah, fair enough.

Comment: @dutt: Not like some of those matter, but the C standard takes it to heart to support everything from running on an banana to a supercomputer. And bananas, last time I checked used 23-bit pointers and 5-bit words. :)

Comment: @Linuxios Haha :D Regarding weird sizes; a couple of years ago I developed an interface for an IR camera that took everything as 24bit variables. That got slightly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Well, I guess there is one. `sizeof()` is still easier though. If you can, use it. Otherwise, go with @dasblinkinlight's answer above.

There is no way to find the size of a type platform agnostically without sizeof. I don'w see why you wouldn't want to use it though. However, if you're willing to make your code convoluted and terrible, and platform dependent, you can add preprocessor statements to check compiler and target architecture, and depending on that, find the value from know values.

Comment: The sentence beginning “There is no way…” is false. Additionally, “But not an official one” is also incorrect. It is permissible under the C standard to increment a pointer one beyond an object and to convert that pointer and the pointer to the object to pointers to `char` and to subtract them.

Answer (score -2):

Use pointer arthimetic and casting

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
  int age, salary;
  char name[12];
  char address[6][20];

      };

typedef struct person EMPLOYEE;

main() {
EMPLOYEE a;
EMPLOYEE *x,*y;

x=&a;
y=x+1;
printf ("pointer arith %d\n", (int)((int)y-(int)x));
printf ("sizeof %ld\n", sizeof(a));
}
```