# how to know size of int without sizeof

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [size of a datatype without using sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219199/size-of-a-datatype-without-using-sizeof)

This is question asked in a C interview I wanted to know what is the correct logic for this

If you are not having a sizeof operator in C, how will you get to know
the size of an int ?

Comment: @Bo Persson on that thread people told it to be a stupid question this is an interview question.I read that link and any good way is not mentioned.Let me know how you will approach this problem.

Comment: It's not quite a dupe, since that other question also forbids declaring a variable of type `int`, which this permits. But there are plenty of answers over there that will work in practice. Charles Bailey's answer is UB because it's UB to add 1 to a null pointer, but it's going to work on any ordinary flat memory model.

Comment: if(UINT_MAX == 65535) size = 2; else if(UINT_MAX == 4294967296) size=4; else if(...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an array[*]:

```
int a[2];
int sizeof_int = (char*)(a+1) - (char*)(a);
```

Actually, due to a note in the section on pointer arithmetic, you don't even need an array, because for the purposes of pointer arithmetic an object behaves like an array of size 1, and an off-the-end pointer is legal for an array:

```
int a;
int sizeof_int = (char*)((&a)+1) - (char*)(&a);
```

[*] By which I mean, "a solution to the puzzle posed is to use an array". Don't actually use an array, use `sizeof`!

Comment: that was perfect I just wrote it on my system but what I am not able to understand is (char *)(a+1) -(char *)(a);

What did this line do ?

Comment: `a+1` is a pointer to `a[1]`, and `a` decays to a pointer to `a[0]`. So it calculates the difference in chars between a pointer to `a[1]` and a pointer to `a[0]`. That is, the number of chars occupied by `a[0]`.

Comment: can is it necessary to type caste that to char *,I mean why can't we use int * for that?

Comment: If you use `int*` then the result will be 1. It shouldn't be surprising that `(a+1) - a == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to calculate the address difference between two consecutive int variables.

Comment: That doesn't take into account padding / alignment optimization.

Comment: If we are dealing with a simple case, we should not bother about optimization et al.

Comment: @Joe: If you have `int a[2];`, then `(char *)a[1] - (char *)a[0]` should give you the correct result.

Comment: @Gunner assuming I go with your approach then how will you find two consecutive int variable?

Comment: @Gunner: Only chars are guaranteed to be laid out continously in memory, so this is not a portable option.

Comment: @Registered User: Look at code snippet provided by Oli Charlesworth.

Answer (score 0):

I think of two ways. One is to print '-1' as a unsigned value and deduce the size basing on the number that is printed. Second is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int size()
{
  int a = 1;
  int size = 1;
  while(a<<=1)
    size++;
  return size;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Size of int: %d\n", size());
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: no, first of all you go for the width of an `int`, here and not the size. interview failed :(( Then even to know the size these methods wouldn't do in all cases. `unsigned` is not necessarily just one value bit larger than `signed` and left shift of signed types is very subtle, it mustn't do necessarily what you think it does.

Comment: @Jens: `unsigned` does have the same *size* as `int`, though, for what that's worth. So in the absence of padding bits, they have the same width, so this code with an `unsigned a` would work to tell you the width of both. With padding the width doesn't tell you the size at all.

Comment: overflow behaviour is just defined for unsigned types in C++ ( > Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number
of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer)

Comment: @Steve, exactly, knowing the width wouldn't tell anything for sure about the size, since you wouldn't know about padding bits or not. Then there is no arithmetic to tell the width of the signed type from the unsigned one.

Answer (score 0):

Declare int, init it to -1.  Repeatedly '<<1' it until it's 0. Number of shifts requried = size in bits.  '<<3' for size in bytes.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Answer is off-by-one on ones' complement machines ;-p. Also, it's UB to left-shift a negative number, but you can use `unsigned int` instead of `int` since they're guaranteed to have the same size and width. That deals with the ones' complement issue too. And btw this tells you the width, not the size. `int` is allowed to have padding bits, not that it ever does in practice.

Comment: no, see my comments on @KasigiYabu's answer

Comment: Aaarrgghh!  If I ever work on a ones complement machine, I'll be sure to test that <g>