# Implement your own sizeof

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [size of a datatype without using sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219199/size-of-a-datatype-without-using-sizeof)

One of my friend recently appeared in NVIDIA interview where he was asked to `implement his own sizeof  in C`. I tried to do the same for practice and successfully write two different definitions of `sizeof` one of which can handle variables and other can handle datatypes but I am unable to merge the two. Is there any way to do so? Also, is it possible to implement a complete `sizeof` in C.

Handle types like `int`, `char` etc

```
#define my_sizeof(type) ((size_t)(((type *)0) + 1))
```

Handles variables like `x`

```
#define my_sizeof(var) (size_t)((char *)(&var+1)-(char*)(&var))
```

Comment: Of course, these only work because the compiler is effectively calling sizeof() under the hood... :)

Comment: It will be a good idea for a learner like you to implement container_of and offset_of macros. Good learning!

Comment: One reason that it's hard/impossible is of course that `sizeof` is not a function. This question is a little like "is there a way to implement `=` in C, without using `=`?".

Answer (score 1):

Good question

1. I don't see a way to merge the two.
2. The implementation to handle the second is unsafe

what if the user does

```
sizeof (*ptr)

sizeof (func())
```

Comment: i thought of those also but there can be a large number of other ways too to use sizeof... i decided to first try to implement the most common ones and then the more complex one ... but i am stuck on the merging part ....