# C - can't use my sizeof implementation as an array size

Tags: c

I implemented sizeof [as recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862991/implement-your-own-sizeof). it work ok when I want to print the size of a variable ,but I can't use it as a array size.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define my_sizeof(var) (size_t)((char *)(&var+1)-(char*)(&var))

int s = 7;

void main()
{
    int arr[sizeof(s)]; //works OK
    int arr2[my_sizeof(s)];//error
    printf("%d\n", my_sizeof(s));//works OK
    int temp = 0;
}
```

```
Error   1   error C2057: expected constant expression
Error   2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
Error   3   error C2133: 'arr2' : unknown size
```

Comment: That's right, you can't. Why do you expect to be able to?

Comment: Sorry, but why is it recommended to do that? What is wrong with the regular `sizeof`?

Comment: Just use `sizeof`, problem solved...

Comment: I can use sizeof, but I a am trying to learn and understand c.

Comment: [It's your compiler.](http://ideone.com/VMV2vz) VS does not have full C99 support.

Comment: P.S. Visual C++ does have a C compiler, though it's outdated; C89 has been superseded by C99, which has been revised as C11... If you should ever have to compile C99-compliant code (and there *is* a lot of it) using MSVC++, you'll have to hack yourself back into the 80s...

Comment: it's supposed to work, if it's C99 compliant. it's just vla instead of static one.

Comment: Re-implementing a core operator is not a good way to learn and understand the language.

Comment: Oh, and one other thing, since one pointer subtracted from another results in a `ptrdiff_t` and `%d` is expected to correspond to an `int` (*not* `ptrdiff_t`) argument, you're invoking undefined behaviour... Once you have a C99 compiler, you'll want to use `%tu` instead.

Comment: Come on ppl, this works in C99... sometimes. What if the array is static, or a struct member?

Answer (score 6):

Your implementation `my_sizeof` is not exactly equivalent to to the `sizeof` operator in C, which is a compile time operator whereas yours can only calculate size at run time.

So,

```
int arr[sizeof(s)];
```

declares an array with size `sizeof(s)` whereas

```
int arr2[my_sizeof(s)];
```

does the the same but the the array size is not calculated at compile time but runtime. For this to work, you'll need the support of C99's [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which your compiler doesn't support and errors out.

Comment: Technically, `sizeof` is not strictly a compile-time operator for VLAs... and heck, a compiler isn't even required.

Answer (score 2):

When you define

```
int arr[sizeof(s)];
```

the compiler allocates its size in the stack as soon as it enters the function, then it needs a constant expression that can evaluate at compile time not a run time ( this could be changed at C99). With my_sizeof you are using pointer arithmetic that must be solved at runtime.

You could use `my_sizeof()` if you allocate the array in the heap using `malloc()`

Answer (score 2):

just let you know, you need to differentiate compile time and run time. these two concepts are critically different in C world.

for example, following code is valid, since it gets the size during compile time:

```
typedef struct {
    char[sizeof(s)] chars;
} anon_struct;
```

however, following is not valid, since the size is unknown until run time and VLA doesn't support in compositional type definition:

```
typedef struct {
    char[my_sizeof(s)] chars;
} anon_struct;
```

suggest you to buy a good text book and have a good read.

Comment: thanks. if global variable is allocated in compiler time, why I can't use the value (not the size)  of a global variable as the array size?

Comment: @ZagGol why you want to do this? as the wording shows, variable is **varying**. it's not possible to know what the size should be if you put the size of array inside of a variable. in this condition, macro is more preferable.

Comment: I am trying to learn and understand the logic of the language.

Comment: @ZagGol C is a very reasonable language. everything happens without any magic. so you can image given the task can you accomplish it with that information? then you will have the answer

Answer (score 0):

gcc can compile this on Ubuntu.  The problem you're seeing is likely due to the address not yet known at compile time.  It will be known at runtime, though, so it looks like gcc does what it takes to make this work "under the hood".  But I gather your compiler is MS-based.

I should add, the line that compiles will allocate arr with a number of int's equal to the number of bytes required for one int (s).  That is probably not what you normally want.  I understand if it's just an exercise for comparison, though.