# What is the meaning of (data type*)0

Tags: c

I have gone through [sizeof operator equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219199/size-of-a-datatype-without-using-sizeof).

```
size_t size = (size_t)(1 + ((X*)0));
```

But could not able to understand what is the meaning of `(int*)0 or (int*)1000`.

What does it **tell** to the compiler? And why **one is added** to them? Could you please elaborate it.

Comment: IT just makes the whatever number an address to an int or whatever you want it to be. The plus one just moves the address. You could also do plus 500 and it would achieve the same result.

Comment: @Flo: I understood for 500 also it works and gives me result as 2000. But how multiplies 500 * 4?

Comment: Each pointer is 4 bytes long. so when you had (int *)500 it becomes 2000. If you had (char)500 it will stay as 500 because char types are only one byte long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(int *)0` means "treat 0 as the address of an integer".  Adding one to this obtains the address of the "next" integer in memory.  Converting the result back to an integer therefore gives you the size of an integer.

However, this relies on **undefined behaviour**, so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Suppose an integer is at location 0, what's the guarantee that by adding 1 it will give you address of next integer? Because we never know that next location one stores integer or chracter or so on?

Comment: Would `(size_t)((1 + ((X*)0))-((X*)0))` be a better choice? I mean, second best to `sizeof(X)`?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: `T *p; p = p + 1;` is the same as `T *p; p = (T *)((char *)p + 1);`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I don't know.  Why would that be any better?

Comment: I know it does not guarantee to yield `sizeof(X)`, but what makes it *undefined*, not just unspecified?

Comment: @hamstergene: See 6.3.2.3 p.5,6 of the C99 standard.  See also 6.5.6 p.8.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth [Because it wouldn't assume that the value of NULL pointer is zero](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I'm not sure it is reliant on that assumption.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, it does rely upon the "null pointer is zero" assumption: C++99 standard, section 6.3.2.3.3, says that casting zero to a pointer type yields a null pointer, which may not be zero.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: Adding 1 to a pointer value advances the pointer to the next available address for an object of the pointed-to type, regardless of whether a value of that type is being stored there or not.  IOW, if I'm currently pointing to an `int` value, the next available `int` address will be `sizeof (int)` bytes from the current address.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ah, of course.  So on these esoteric platforms, the result of `(size_t)((int*)0 + 1)` will be `NULL_PTR_REPRESENTATION + 1`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Does it mean that if I by any means create a non-null pointer that does not point to a valid object or to one past the last object of an array, I'm invoking UB?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think creating one is fine, only _using_ it (e.g. as an operand of `+` or `-`) invokes UB.

Answer (score 1):

This just creates a pointer that points to address 0.
Adding 1 to it does increment on a pointer.
This has the effect of advancing the address with the size of the data type.
In the example, size will contain the size of class X since the pointer will be advanced by the size of the class X and since the initial pointer value is zero.

Answer (score 1):

> understand what is the meaning of `(int*)0` or `(int*)1000`.

Those are just casts, exactly the same as the second line here:

```
int a = 25;
short b = (short)a;
```

Casting `a` to `short` allows you to assign the value to `b`, which is typed as a `short`. It's the same thing with `(int*)0` -- you're just telling the compiler to treat `0` as a pointer to an `int`.

The thing about casting is that you're essentially telling the compiler: "Look, I know what I'm doing here, so do what I tell you and stop complaining about types not matching." And that means that you really do need to know what you're doing, and what the effect in the final code is. Any code that includes an expression like `(int*)1000` is likely to be a) highly suspect and b) very dependent on the compiler and the particulars of the platform that the code was written for. It might possibly make sense in some sort of embedded system where you know for darn sure what's going to be at memory location 1000 because you control the entire system. In general, you should avoid code like that.